# query and variable post

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving address from a `search.php` and then send that value to `map.php`. I can also get the id from given address.

My question is how can I save the value of `$row['id']` as a variable?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['w1'])){
        $id_1 = $_GET['w1'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,'marker'); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM markermap WHERE address= '".$id_1."'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));     

        echo'<table class="responstable">';

        if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['id'].'  </td>';
                echo '</tr>';

            }
        } else {
            echo "No record available";
        }
    } else {  
        echo 'No id is comming';
    }

    echo'</table>';

?>
```

Comment: `$row['id']` *is* a variable.

Comment: you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Jay How can I assign to different value then? I want to $id_2 = $row['id']; ??

Comment: I know Marc, I am going to use prepared statement. This is on my local for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$row_id = $row['id'];
```

$row['id'] is already a variable so why do you want to assign it to another variable?
And try to bind values from $_GET cause it's really not safe to put them straight into query. Maybe try PDO.

Comment: Mateusz it is more like the following. <?php $id_2 = $_GET['id'];
 echo "$id_2";
 ?>

Comment: Yup but it id the same as: echo $_GET['id'];

Comment: Thanks Mateusz. I am going to make some changes and see if that works. You can tell I am new to this. :)

Comment: No problem :) Keep exploring :)